# Transit through Shenzhen (SZX) without leaving the airport

Tags: visas, transit, china, new-zealand-citizens, shenzhen

I am a New Zealand citizen wishing to transit through SZX without leaving the airport. I am seeking clarification on whether I will need a transit visa to proceed with this plan. I am flying from Auckland to Shenzhen then onward to Jakarta, hopefully with only a few hours (less than 5) layover.

I have found [this site](https://thenanfang.com/shenzhen-now-offers-72-hour-visa-free-entry/), which states Shenzhen is implementing a 72-hour TWOV.

But when I look at Timatic, it seems to state no TWOV is possible at SZX. Just to clarify, I don't want to leave the airport, and my layover will only be a few hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=cn&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=tw&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Transit without visa (TWOV) is **not** possible at Fuzhou (FOC), **Shenzhen (SZX)** and Yanji (YNJ).

TWOV generally means transiting without exiting the transit area. SZX, however, does not have a dedicated transit corridor in the first place, nor does it have any short-visit TWOV arrangement whereby you're allowed to enter China.

In other words, you **do** need a transit visa

Comment: To update the information, the whole Guangdong region now has 144-hour TWOV, so someone in the OP's situation in 2018 doesn't need a visa. They will however need to go through immigration and customs, and check in again.